# NotImplementedError: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ubuntu, wsl-2

I am testing a Rails project on Windows 10 WSL2. I was able to run `rails server` with no problem but when I run `rails test test/integration`, I get `NotImplementedError: fork() function is unimplemented on this machine` error 
Ruby version: `ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]` 
Rails version: `Rails 5.2.0` 
Ubuntu: 20.04

Answer (score 2):

On this [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Process.html#method-c-fork), it is said that

> fork(2) is not available on some platforms like Windows and NetBSD 4. Therefore you should use spawn() instead of fork().

So your gem for test is trying to call this function. You need to open the ruby gem in a text editor and change the script where it is written the function **fork()**, replacing with **spawn()**.
From this:

```
static VALUE
rb_f_fork(VALUE obj)
{
    rb_pid_t pid;

    switch (pid = rb_fork_ruby(NULL)) {
      case 0:
        rb_thread_atfork();
        if (rb_block_given_p()) {
            int status;
            rb_protect(rb_yield, Qundef, &status);
            ruby_stop(status);
        }
        return Qnil;

      case -1:
        rb_sys_fail("fork(2)");
        return Qnil;

      default:
        return PIDT2NUM(pid);
    }
}
```

To this

```
static VALUE
rb_f_fork(VALUE obj)
{
    rb_pid_t pid;

    switch (pid = rb_fork_ruby(NULL)) {
      case 0:
        rb_thread_atfork();
        if (rb_block_given_p()) {
            int status;
            rb_protect(rb_yield, Qundef, &status);
            ruby_stop(status);
        }
        return Qnil;

      case -1:
        rb_sys_fail("spawn(2)");
        return Qnil;

      default:
        return PIDT2NUM(pid);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can test the integration maintaining a separated copy of your rails app in a windows environment:
clone it from your github

`git clone <the path for your remote repository>`

And then, in your gemfile, uncomment the gems below the last line where it is said:

`Windows does not have ...`

From this
`#gem zinfo [...]`

To this:

`gem zinfo [...]`

By the last, run

`bundle install`

to update your lock.gemfile.

Comment: The OP is not using Windows but WSL2, which is a proper Linux system with a proper Linux kernel running virtualized on top of a stripped down Hyper-V hypervisor.

Comment: This fact makes me wondering how the gem, on its script shell installation, keeps deciding following part of windows script installation instruction. The same had happened in my machine with WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the documentation but most probably, WSL does not support `fork()` function.

You can try using [`spawn()`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/spawn) instead of `fork()`.

Comment: The OP is specifically using *WSL2* which is fundamentally different from WSL1. You should make clear which version you refer to when you say that "WSL does not support `fork()` function". In particular, WSL2 is a proper Linux system with a proper Linux kernel running virtualized on top of a stripped down Hyper-V hypervisor.